# toggle div using for loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

just wondering what went wrong.. i have two div named click_1 and click_2.. and i want to toggle the div named hide corresponding with their numbers.. lets say click_1 with hide_1 and click_2 with hide_2.. but when i ran the code only click_1 is functioning .. what seems to be wrong... newbie here.. recently learned jquery

```
    <div id='click_1'>
        <div id='hide_1'></div>
    </div>
    <div id='click_2'>
        <div id='hide_2'></div>
    </div>

    <script>
    function toggle_div(id_A,id_B){
       for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
           var new_A = id_A + i;
           var new_B = id_B + i;

           $(new_A).click(function(){
                  $(new_B).toggle();
              });  
       }
    }

    toggle_div('click_','hide_');

    </script>
```

Comment: amm.. sorry.. just for loop i guess.. do you think you can fix it?

Comment: I had done with answer almost. But answer was posted just like a second ago. So I didn't post that. @Nope

Comment: please write questions so they are easy to understand. stackoverflow is not a chat, don't use ... everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because your id selectors are missing the `#` prefix:

```
toggle_div('#click_', '#hide_');
```

However you should note that you will also need to use a closure for this pattern to work otherwise the `new_B` element will always be the last one referenced in the `for` loop.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='click_1'>
  click 1
  <div id='hide_1'>hide 1</div>
</div>
<div id='click_2'>  
  click 2
  <div id='hide_2'>hide 2</div>
</div>

<script>
  function toggle_div(id_A, id_B) {
    for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
      var new_A = id_A + i;
      var new_B = id_B + i;

      (function(a, b) {
        $(a).click(function() {
          $(b).toggle();
        })
      })(new_A, new_B);
    }
  }

  toggle_div('#click_', '#hide_');
</script>
```

As you can see this is very verbose, rather complicated and hardly extensible. A *much* better approach is to use generic classes and DOM traversal to repeat the same logic on common HTML structures.

To achieve this put common classes on the elements to be clicked and the elements to toggle. Then in the single `click` event handler you can use the `this` keyword to reference the element which was clicked, then `find()` the element to toggle within that. Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.click').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.hide').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">
  click 1
  <div class="hide">hide 1</div>
</div>
<div class="click">
  click 2
  <div class="hide">hide 2</div>
</div>
<div class="click">
  click 3
  <div class="hide">hide 3</div>
</div>
```

Also note that this pattern means that you can have an infinite number of `.click` elements with matching `.hide` content without ever needing to update your JS code.

Comment: ahh... so thats it!... you need to have a closure function.. your the best man... by the way.. i like your simplified code...thanks a bunch..^_^

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I'd strongly suggest you use the latter pattern, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to use `for loop` for click event ! If you have id like that your can handle by that clicked id split ....

```js
$("[id^='click_']").on("click",function () {
  $('#hide_'+this.id.split('_')[1]).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='click_1'>
    Click1
        <div id='hide_1'>hide1</div>
    </div>
    <div id='click_2'>
    Click2
        <div id='hide_2'>hide2</div>
    </div>
```